# Lobby creator decides for all when game start

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, spring, rest

I have a question regarding a problem I have to tackle:

I am doing an React project which is a little game. In this game the users can create different lobbies. Now my goal is, that the creator of a game lobby can decide, when the actual game should start. When s/he does that, the creator and the other users should be redirected to the actual game.
Does anyone have an approach for that?

Best regards